# How to decode flexible xml in GO?

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I have the following xml:

```
    ...
    <solution>
      <ContainerBlockElement>
        <Paragraph>
           <Paragraph>
              Foo
           </Paragraph>
           <Paragraph>
              bar
           </Paragraph>
       </Paragraph>
     </ContainerBlockElement>
   </solution>
   ...
```

I want to extract the  content but the problem is: The server can send me the second structure:

```
    ...
    <solution>
      <ContainerBlockElement>
        <Paragraph>
          baz
        </Paragraph>
      </ContainerBlockElement>
    </solution>
    ...
```

I've tried to use this struct in go to decode but it doesn't work:

```
       type Blah struct {
           ...
    Solutions           []string     `xml:"solution>ContainerBlockElement>Paragraph"`
    Solutions2Paragraph []string         `xml:"solution>ContainerBlockElement>Paragraph>Paragraph"`

}
```

How can I decode this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With unpredictable structures, deserializing into a struct is not going to work. Instead, you'll be better off using the streaming mode of the XML parser using [`xml.Decoder.Token`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Token) to parse elements in order and handle them as necessary.

```
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile) 
solutions := make([]string,0,0)

for { 
    t, _ := decoder.Token() 
    if t == nil { 
        break 
    }
    switch se := t.(type) { 
    case xml.StartElement: 
        if se.Name.Local == "Paragraph" {
            // Get the next token after the Paragraph start element, which will be the tag contents
            innerText,ok := decoder.Token().(xml.CharData)
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            solutions = append(solutions, string(innerText))
        }
    }
}
```

This code is untested but should provide a decent starting point.